# Trying to Export/Import Xenforo Database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, migration, xenforo

I am working on a Xenforo forum and we are moving to a different server with the same domain.

The files are already copied over the only issue is the database now.

I can export the database fine but the issue is when I g to import it into the new database through phpmyadmin.

A lot of the tables import fine but then when it gets to this table it throws an error saying the formatting is off.

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `xf_bb_code_media_site` (

 `media_site_id` VARBINARY( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
 `site_title` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `site_url` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `match_urls` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `match_is_regex` TINYINT( 3 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7
```

Comment: What's `COMMENT` doing there?

Comment: Not sure, when I exported it out of the old phpmyadmin thats what was in there. Should I edit the .sql file and remove "COMMENT" and try that?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a bug from an old version of phpMyAdmin which has already been fixed. You should upgrade your phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line mysql to export and import instead of phpMyAdmin this will solve your problem.

To export a SQL database use mysqldump

```
mysqldump –u USERNAME–p DB_NAME > EXPORTED_DB.sql
```

to import a SQL databse first upload it to your server in a private folder, then import like so:

```
mysql --user="USERNAME" --password="PASSWORD" DB_NAME < "/home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/private/EXPORTED_DB.sql"
```

Always backup first for safety.